# Some font-awesome icons are not working, but others do

Tags: html, font-awesome

I have included the font-awesome via `<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/[myid].js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`. I have several icons, some are working and some are not:

```
<i class="fa-solid fa-plug-circle-bolt"></i>
```

works but

```
<i class="fa fa-arrow-down-arrow-up"></i>
```

does not. In the font awesome kit settings I have the "webfont" and "Version 6.x" options.

Comment: No icon exists with the name `fa-arrow-down-arrow-up`. Please double check the icon name.

Comment: @UtkarshVishnoi https://fontawesome.com/icons/arrow-down-arrow-up?s=solid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have some premium icons which will not appear with the free plans. You should filter on "free".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeGOl.png.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I got confused by their site and thought "if they show it to me, it's free". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're browsing the icon pack of the same version as your kit/script.
For example, if you're using the header script/fontawesome kit for fontwesome version 5, some icons from fontawesome version 6 wouldn't work.
Also, if you're on the free plan of Fontawesome, premium icons also won't work.

Comment: Yes, it is a premium icon. I got confused by their site and thought "if they show it to me, it's free". Thanks!

Comment: You're most welcome :)